# Android Exploit Development Lab

Tags: android, vulnerability, reverse-engineering, exploit-development, fuzzing

Looking to setup an exploit development environment to do the following:

1. Fuzz Android libraries to find new vulnerabilities
2. Re-create already existing bugs/vulnerabilities based on bug fixes found on the AOSP (write POC)
3. Exploit development for already known vulnerabilities

Would like to know what are the best fuzzing frameworks and debuggers that fit best for Android along with other requirements

Comment: How do you define "best"?

Comment: Something well suited for ARM architecture, all in one package if possible (assembler, debugger, fuzzer, emulator support). I am possibly looking for an Android reverse engineering / exploit development / fuzzing starter kit. A tutorial or guide reference maybe ? - Already did my research, but found nothing consistent to build on. Thanks

Comment: This really isn't what we deal with here. Recommendations like this could go on forever and are not well-suited to a Q&A format.

Comment: I wish you luck in your project, though. Have you tried places like Reddit?

Comment: Not really, I will do that. Thank you for your feedback !